# Execution time too long Google AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-contacts-api

I created this script to capitalize family names in Google Contacts.
Only the script takes too much time.
An idea ?

```
function nomDeFamilleEnMajuscules() {
  Logger.clear();
  var contacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();
  for (var i in contacts) {
    var nomDeFamille = contacts[i].getFamilyName();
    if (nomDeFamille != '') {
      Logger.log("Nom de famille " + contacts[i].getFamilyName());
      var nomDeFamilleMajuscules = nomDeFamille.toUpperCase();
      var iDContact = contacts[i].getId();
      var contact = ContactsApp.getContactById(iDContact);
      contact.setFamilyName(nomDeFamilleMajuscules);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only update a contact if it's not capitalized yet:

```
    ...
    if(nomDeFamilleMajuscules != nomDeFamille) {
        var iDContact = contacts[i].getId();
        var contact = ContactsApp.getContactById(iDContact);
        contact.setFamilyName(nomDeFamilleMajuscules);
    }
    ...
```

You may have to run the script a few times for it to apply for all contacts, but at least it won't start over each time.

`ContactsApp.getContactById` probably takes a good chunk of time, so only executing it when it's actually needed should speed it up a good bit.

Comment: Did you try it and did it help?

Comment: Yes and indeed it is faster

Comment: Feel free to give it an upvote, then, and accept it if it solves your original question.

Comment: For a very large number of contacts, it is still too slow.
But I did not find a way to make running faster

Comment: Maybe if you rerun it, it will work faster the second time?